# Assign a mount point folder path to a drive using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, disk-partitioning

I have a server that is provisioned with several disks. One for an OS, one for programs etc., and the remaining are to be mounted to empty NTFS folders.

```
Disk 0: C:
Disk 1: G:
Disk 2: G:\Folder01\
Disk 3: G:\Folder02\
```

This is fairly straightforward through the GUI: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321.aspx

But, I need to automate so I need to figure out how to do this with PowerShell.
I have hit several dead ends:

I thought I was making some progress with [Get-Disk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848657(v=wps.630).aspx), [Initialize-Disk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848708(v=wps.630).aspx), and [New-Partition](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848714(v=wps.630).aspx)

```psh
$Disk = Get-Disk 2
$Disk | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR
$Disk | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -MbrType IFS
$Partition = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $Disk.Number
```

From here, I was hoping to do something like:

```psh
New-Volume $Partition -FriendlyName Folder01 -AccessPath F:\Folder01 -FileSystem NTFS
```

But that doesn't produce any output and I noticed that earlier when I created a partition, it created a volume as well.

I'm thinking that [New-Volume](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454966(v=wps.630).aspx) might be the wrong command because the help indicates that the input object should be a MSFT_StoragePool object.

I tried to go down that path a little ways with commands like: [Get-PhysicalDisk](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848686(v=wps.630).aspx), [New-StoragePool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848689(v=wps.630).aspx), [Get-StoragePool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848654(v=wps.630).aspx)

```psh
$Disk = Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName PhysicalDisk2
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName Pool2 -StorageSubsystemFriendlyName "Storage Spaces*" -PhysicalDisks $Disk
$Pool = Get-StoragePool Pool2
New-Volume -FriendlyName Folder01 -AccessPath G:\Folder01 -FileSystem NTFS -InputObject $Pool
```

But I just get an error message at this point for invalid parameters, which I think is weird because I was able to use Get-Member to confirm that $Pool is a MSFT_StoragePool.

I've also noticed that after creating that storage pool, my disk disappeared from Disk Management and no longer shows up with Get-Disk

I think that shows that Storage Pools are something completely different from what I want to actually do.

How do I assign a drive to an NTFS Folder with Powershell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Commandlet that I needed was [Add-PartitionAccessPath](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848703(v=wps.630).aspx)

I set things up the way I wanted through the GUI on disk 2, created a partion on Disk 3 and then carefully compared the properties.
The key was here:

```psh
(Get-Partition -DiskNumber 2).AccessPaths
(Get-Partition -DiskNumber 3).AccessPaths
```

There was an additional AccessPath for Disk2, which led me across a number of MSDN articles looking for a method, until I finally found that there already is a command for it.

The following command sealed the deal:

```psh
$Partition | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath "G:\Folder01"
```

For reference, here's the full solution:

```psh
$Disk = Get-Disk 3
# $Disk | Clear-Disk -RemoveData -Confirm:$false
$Disk | Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR
$disk | New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -MbrType IFS
$Partition = Get-Partition -DiskNumber $Disk.Number
$Partition | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -Confirm:$false
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "G:\Folder01"
$Partition | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath "G:\Folder01"
```

Answer (score 2):

How to assign a drive to a NTFS Folder in Powershell using [Command Line](http://lifehacker.com/267728/give-a-folder-its-very-own-drive-letter):

```
cmd /c 'subst G: "C:\Folder1"'
```

Note: Explorer is showing the same size of the folder as the C:.

Comment: I don't think this is going to accomplish what I want, but I'm going to give it a try and see if the result is identical to what I get when I do it via GUI.

I initialized a disk and assigned it to J:, I then tried the command:
subst J: G:\Folder01
and got 
Invalid parameter - J:

I'm running sfc /scannow to see if I can resolve that issue.

Comment: Ok, I figured out why this isn't working for me. Subst allows me to take a drive letter that's currently unassigned and use it as a shorctut to another path. That's cool, but not what I'm actually trying to do here. I want to take a "drive" by which I mean a physical or virtual disk, and mount it to a folder, so that when I put files into that folder, they're stored on that disk.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at putting files into some folder, and expect them to end up being stored on some disk then there's `MOUNTVOL`.

To find drive/volume name:

```
MOUNTVOL
```

TO remove the drive letter & instead mount on an empty NTFS folder:

```
mountvol e: /d
mountvol c:\<path> <volume name> 
eg. mountvol c:\fakedisk\ \\?\Volume{########-####-####-####-############}\
```

So in above example, everytime to write to c:\fakedisk\ folder, the data will end up in what used to be e: drive (disk/device). This is opposite to `subst`, which "Associates a path with a drive letter
", so writing data to the drive will get stored in that path/folder.

Tested on Win 10
CMD

Comment: This might be useful on the fly, but a key part of the problem I was trying to solve was automating/scripting the task.

To link this command to the rest of the script, you'd need to provide the guid.
I think you can get that with `$Partition.guid ` within the original example, but I haven't tested it.

I think Add-PartitionAccessPath is more straightforward, but having multiple ways of solving a problem is always helpful.

Comment: To find drive/volume name (GUID): type `MOUNTVOL`. It will list "values for VolumeName along with current mount points". Then select GUID associated with the mount point to your drive or folder path.

Comment: Sure, but again, the task here is to automate the process. PowerShell was listed as a requirement in the question, although non-PowerShell commands certainly can be incorporated if necessary. If one were to use `MOUNTVOL`, then the next step would be to parse the output, which honestly seems like a challenging task. If I'm going to do everything manually, I might as well just use the GUI.

Comment: You mean to automatically select the GUID for the selected drive?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder exists before running this command:

```
$Partition | Add-PartitionAccessPath -AccessPath "G:\Folder01"
```

Comment: You probably should add that as a comment to my solution above instead of as a separate answer. I've modified my solution to include a step to create the folder.